# Navigation Component - Popup stack behavior with deeplink

Tags: android, navigation

I have navigation like this

Splash -> walkthrough   -> a) Register
-> b) Login

Deeplink -> VerifyUser  -> Login

After registration, I get email with a link which I have used for deeplinking, this link navigates to VerifyUser fragment and which navigates to Login if verification fails. I want to navigate to Login but on Login I also want to go back to walkthrough fragment if back pressed. Here are my defined actions. Let me know what I am doing wrong here for such behavior.
What happens now is when I go from VerifyFragment to Login and on Login when I press back, it again takes me to VerifyFragment. May I know why is this happening?
Thanks

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/verifyFragment"
    android:name="com.app.package.verifyUser.verify.VerifyFragment"
    android:label="VerifyRegistrationFragment">
  <action
        android:id="@+id/action_verifyFragment_to_loginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@+id/walkThroughFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    <argument
        android:name="userId"
        app:argType="string" />
    <argument
        android:name="code"
        app:argType="string" />

    <deepLink app:uri="https://url.com/ConfirmEmail?userId={userId}&amp;code={code}" />

</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/walkThroughFragment"
    android:name="com.app.package.walkthrough.WalkThroughFragment"
    android:label="walkThroughFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_walkthrough">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_walkThroughFragment_to_loginFragment"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_walkThroughFragment_to_registerFragment"
        app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:name="com.app.package.login.LoginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_login"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registerFragment"
        app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_onBoardingFragment"
        app:destination="@id/onBoardingFragment" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_forgotPassword"
        app:destination="@id/forgotPassword" />
    
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from verify to login action tag :

```
app:popUpToInclusive="true"
```